# Add Linear Discriminant Analysis Line and Show Equation on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, linear-discriminant, mass

Rather than using an incorrect line generated by `lm` using `geom_smooth(method = lm`), I wanted to plot the line that a linear discriminant analysis would consider "0." I understand how to get the output data with LD1 and LD2, but not the specific equation it generates, or how to add this line to a ggplot with the X and Y values used as an input.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(MASS)
library(dplyr)
library(ggpubr)
library(gridExtra)
##Create dataframe
Size<-c(6,6,6,8,8,8,10,10,10,12,12,12,15,15,15,6,6,8,8,8,10,10,10,12,12,12,15,15,15,6,6,6,8,10,10,10,12,12,12,15,15,6,8,8,8,10,10,10,12,12,15,15)

Category<-c("ClassII", "ClassII", "ClassII", "ClassII", "ClassII", "ClassII", "ClassII", "ClassII", "ClassII", "ClassII", "ClassII", "ClassII", "ClassII", "ClassII", "ClassII", "ClassIII", "ClassIII", "ClassIII", "ClassIII", "ClassIII", "ClassIII", "ClassIII", "ClassIII", "ClassIII", "ClassIII", "ClassIII", "ClassIII", "ClassIII", "ClassIII", "ClassI", "ClassI", "ClassI", "ClassI", "ClassI", "ClassI", "ClassI", "ClassI", "ClassI", "ClassI", "ClassI", "ClassI", "ClassIV", "ClassIV", "ClassIV", "ClassIV", "ClassIV", "ClassIV", "ClassIV", "ClassIV", "ClassIV", "ClassIV", "ClassIV")

    H<-c(0.4597714,0.3384975,0.2438867,0.5773447,0.5424548,0.5225763,0.5773447,0.5424548,0.5225763,0.6188187,0.5979812,0.5321799,0.6028551,0.4706633,0.4867061,0.3674625,0.3430894,0.3102022,0.4380490,0.4037123,0.3904491,0.3952290,0.3964599,0.5618259,0.5479117,0.6004870,0.5838193,0.5983880,0.5864260,0.6313169,0.5161577,0.5822030,0.6525793,0.4346467,0.4190352,0.4248726,0.5149471,0.5433182,0.4797744,0.5149471,0.5433182,0.3071416,0.3227957,0.5113163,0.5167215,0.3055734,0.2595054,0.2697147,0.1945752,0.1844296,0.4543830,0.4506419)

    D<-c(17.060473,17.247823,17.487762,14.783000,13.305876,11.955035,15.569631,16.330392,15.297604,13.801903,13.316480,12.114558,14.744418,16.776991,14.128221,42.428042,40.711409,45.048931,44.613229,34.386670,23.555482,24.578951,22.834340,16.106533,19.230402,18.609950,25.945419,17.957438,24.540131,9.217218,8.346780,8.350304,8.931497,7.871861,7.627603,8.483040,8.952785,7.902581,4.846481,9.441160,9.461342,34.636275,33.427111,36.670034,19.104717,34.539788,44.268683,38.370184,31.623433,33.561326,45.195551,27.661643)

data<-data.frame(Size,Category,H,D)

##Creates plot I want to add LDA line and equation to
ggplot(data, aes(x=D, y=H)) + geom_point(aes(x = D, y = H, color = data$Size, shape=data$Category), size = 4) + scale_color_gradient(breaks=c(6, 8, 10, 12, 15),low = "blue1", high = "red1")+xlab("D") +ylab("H")+theme_classic()+theme(legend.position = "none")

##LDA
varsDH <- cbind(data$H, data$D)
post_hocDH <-lda(data$Category~ varsDH, CV = F)
plot_ldaDHbyCategory <- data.frame(data[, "H"], lda =predict(post_hocDH)$x)
```

Comment: `lda` is from the MASS package? Please include all libraries used in the code example. Also, don't use `data$Size` _etc_ inside of `aes()`; just use _e.g._. `aes(color = Size)`.

Comment: Yes, from the MASS package. I apologize for not specifying in the code--I have updated with the libraries that were loaded prior to writing this example.